# "Il n'en reste pas moins que"?

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions-idiomatiques

I saw this sentence on wikipedia:

> Il n'en reste pas moins que New York est la ville la plus peuplée du pays depuis 1790, avec 8 622 698 habitants selon le Bureau du recensement des États-Unis.

I don't understand that opening bit, the first six words or so. What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Il n'en reste pas moins*** is an idiom so is hard to interpret word by word.

Literally, that would be:

> It doesn't remain (from what has been said) less than...

i.e.

> The fact remains, nevertheless, that New York is the...